# Fixed image at the bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can someone help me stick an image at the bottom of an `UITableView`? It needs to stay at the bottom if there aren't enough rows and be pushed down otherwise.

[image]

I've tried this code, but it will sit under the last row if there aren't enough to fill the screen.

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "TableBackground")
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.width/image!.size.width * image!.size.height))
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    theTable.tableFooterView = imageView
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just limit table view to take less screen tableView.size.height - imageView.size.height , and put an imageView as a subview to the view controllers view ?

Comment: As shown in the screenshots, the image view should be scrollable and pushed down if the rows fill the table view.